# xpath: getting child node by searching parent attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a KML file for google maps that I want to edit. Here's a stripped-down version:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <Placemark>
            <name>00</name>
            <snippet></snippet>
            <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#Style0-polygon-3-map</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='Two-Digit Districts'>
                    <value>AK-00</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Standard Districts'>
                    <value>AK-AL</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='At Large as District 1'>
                    <value>AK-1</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='Full District Name'>
                    <value>Alaska At Large</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name=''>
                    <value>AK</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData>
        </PlaceMark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

In my php code, I'm digging into each placemark node using SimpleXML:

```
foreach ($kml->Document->Placemark as $placemark) {
    $extendeddata = $placemark->ExtendedData;
}
```

I need to get the `<Data>` node where the `name` attribute matches "At Large as District 1". In the XML tools plugin for NPP, when I take just the `<ExtendedData>...</ExtendedData>` node, this query returns the node I want: `//Data[@name='At Large as District 1']`. However, when I try that same query in PHP:

```
$targetnode = $extendeddata->xpath("//Data[@name='At Large as District 1']")
```

I get an empty array. I don't understand why what should be a perfectly valid xpath query isn't returning any information. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ending tag mismatch.

Replace `</PlaceMark>` with `</Placemark>`

### Code

You have to register with a namespace in order to do an xpath in this case.

```
$extendeddata = simplexml_load_string( $str );
$extendeddata->registerXPathNamespace( 'ns', 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' );
$targetnode = $extendeddata->xpath("//ns:Data[@name='At Large as District 1']");
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => At Large as District 1
                )

            [value] => AK-1
        )

)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The end tag was just me typing the example wrong; in the actual file it was fine. But the namespace was what solved it. Thanks!